# Why my DevExpress v14.1 doesn't have the GridViewEdittingMode component?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

According to the official document of DevExpress : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewEditingModeEnumtopic , the assembly which contains GridViewEditingMode component should be DevExpress.Web.v14.1.dll. However, I tried to add it to my reference, it still said GridViewEditingMode does not exist.  The hash code of my DevExpress.Web.v14.1.dll is SHA256  CFDE95612BA9D4A771DD0236D95A8A1881BE983DC72985205E36134CA37D1075. Worse still, I don't have the project converter in my computer, nor does DevExpress provide v14.1 trial anymore.

Is there any one who knows how to make GridViewEditingMode component be available in a DevExpress v14.1 based project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you faced this breaking change ([Some classes related to DevExpress ASP.NET controls have been moved to the DevExpress.Web namespace](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/WhatsNew/DXperience/files/14.2.3.bc.xml#BC2626)). So, the namespace where the GridViewEditingMode enumeration is implemented was changed from DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView to DevExpress.Web. The following code should work for you.

```
var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "GridView";
    // code
    settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewEditingMode.EditFormAndDisplayRow;
    // code
});
```